# How to unload/remove/replace a Jquery Script if useragent is IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6

This is tricky. I have done a script with jQuery, where an  gets "shaked" if the user puts incorrect values:

```
$('#input-name').addClass('input-bad').effect('shake',{
            direction: 'left',
            distance: 10,
            times: 3}
        , 100 );
```

The problem is that this effect (thanks to jQuery UI) makes the input shake but at the very far right of the page in Internet Explorer 6 (dunno 7/8). The point is remove the shake effect if the user uses this browser. I'm using  for browser detection purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to ensure you are looking at the major revision, i.e. `6`.

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 6) {
   // IE6
}
```

You could also use conditional comment...

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     // IE6
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") {
    // maybe change color to indicate error?
}
else {
    $('#input-name').addClass('input-bad').effect('shake',{
            direction: 'left',
            distance: 10,
            times: 3}
        , 100 );
}
```